# Apache dropping or removing or not storing a header in cache (Edge-Cache-Tag)

Tags: apache, caching, header, aem, cache-control

I have a weird situation where Apache 2.4 won't return a header from its cache. I have a AEM instance in Publisher mode returning these headers as part of its responses:

```
Date: Fri, 22 May 2020 22:26:21 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Edge-Cache-Tag: /en-us/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The flow works basically like this:

- I hit Apache using a URL like https://ip:443/en-us/
- Path gets rewritten to /content/some/other/path
- Apache hits AEM on port 4503 to path /content/some/other/path
- My web app returns a 200, including the headers I put above
- Apache will see that its cache doesn't contain an entry for /content/some/other/path, and will create a cache entry for it.
- Next and finally, Apache returns a 200.

When I hit again Apache to https://ip:443/en-us/, it responds with a 200, but it is not returning "Edge-Cache-Tag" header. I know the response comes from the cache, because first, I see an entry for "/content/some/other/path" in the cache, and if I hit Apache using https://ip:443/en-us/?foo=bar (a query param to bypass the cache), the header comes back, which  means the response comes from the web app actually because the query param makes Apache bypass the cache.

I don't understand why Apache is removing "Edge-Cache-Tag" from its response. I have checked all my Apache config, and I don't have a single instructions to remove headers (like Header unset).
Can't Apache cache "Edge-Cache-Tag"?

Comment: Hi , I am facing same issue , I have a header "Set-Cookie" which returned on an author or publish instance response but not when accessed from a dispatcher. How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of the dispatcher. You have to configure `Edge-Cache-Tag` as one of the cached headers.

https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html

> The `/headers` property allows you to define the HTTP header types that
>   are going to be cached by the Dispatcher. On the first request to an
>   uncached resource, all headers matching one of the configured values
>   (see the configuration sample below) are stored in a separate file,
>   next to the cache file. On subsequent requests to the cached resource,
>   the stored headers are added to the response.

Comment: Isn't this to instruct dispatcher to cache or not cache headers. question is about why dispatcher not sending headers from publish instance to browser through a dispatcher?

Comment: Yes, it is to instruct caching response headers. But I think, this was original question/problem. It said, that with an empty cache the response-header is sent. But if such a request "hit again the Apache" = second request, the response header is missing. So I guessed, that the response header wasn't cached (and not sent when cached results are returned). For uncached responses the Dispatcher doesn't filter any response headers. Only incoming request headers are filtered by the Dispatcher. The response headers can only be removed/overwritten with some direct Apache Header directives.